# List of target sites in flagging wizard

Tags: discussion, feature-request, migration

As a non-moderator, I can flag questions for a multitude of reasons. One is "It doesn't belong here" and then "off topic". After that, a list of possibly suited SE sites is shown along with a generic item.

Currently, only meta.cstheory.SE and stackexchange can be chosen. I think at least math.SE should be included, given how many questions we refer (and should move!) there. Other possible targets are tex.SE and stats.SE.

Who manages this list and how can we influence it?

**Edit:** Crossposted on [meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84902/list-of-target-sites-in-flagging-wizard)

Answer (score 5):

I personally think it is reasonable to include [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/) in the list. We direct users to Math.SE more often than we direct them to SO, therefore it seems as a more natural option (assuming that people on Math.SE don't have objections and we should check that).

I also think it will decrease the amount of moderator intervention in these cases and will help us keep the site research level.

Comment: Since there hasn't been any objections, I am going ask Math.SE guys about this and if they don't have objections I will ask SE admins to add Math.SE to the list.

Comment: update: asked on Math.SE meta for permission to include Math.SE in the list: [migration from cstheory to math](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1966/migration-from-cstheory-to-math-se)

Comment: The feedback from Math.SE users has been positive so I am going to send request to SE admins about this and hopefully they will agree with adding Math.SE to the list.

Answer (score 3):

This might be somthing to ask on meta.SE. In the interim, a close vote for being 'out of scope' allows you to select migration to any site in the SE network. Would that suffice ? In your case, since you don't yet have the rep to issue close votes, you could suggest that in a comment and a mod can then take action appropriately.

Comment: Currently, choosing a site to migrate other than meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com and Stack Overflow when casting a close vote is a moderator privilege.

Comment: Suresh, that is an OK workaround. I noticed, though, that I can recommend moving to other sites on math.SE (i.e. not stackoverflow but stats.SE). So I figured the list has to be configurable.

Comment: @Raphael: The list is configurable, but we first have to form a consensus to change it.

Comment: @Raphael: … or not.  I am not sure any longer.  Some people say that the list is chosen automatically based on the number of questions actually migrated by moderators.