# Flags with more colors?

Tags: discussion, migration, flagging

[Related question.](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1082/list-of-target-sites-in-flagging-wizard)

When you flag a question as "it does not belong to this site", you end-up in the following menu.

[image]

The question is, could it be useful to include some more choices in this menu such us Maths.SE or Physics.SE?

**Update**.  The current opinion seems to be no, for migration is not very well accepted, mods can migrate and users with high-reputation can vote to close posts.

Comment: it is possible to request this from SE admins if the community decides so, but it seems to me that the community is not in favor of migration (by anyone other than the OP) in general.

Comment: Ach soo, I had thought that only mods coud migrate and that this wizard works as a poll-system in order to help them. Do those options above allow anyone to migrate?

Comment: you need to have enough reputation to be able to vote close.

Comment: Perhaps the awaited CS.SE would make more sense than Stackoverflow.

Comment: I realised my question is very similar to [this one](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1082/list-of-target-sites-in-flagging-wizard). Should I close it?

Comment: you can close this as duplicate if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mods can migrate anywhere in the SE network, but even we can't flag something as "for this other SE site"